# Двухмерные динамические массивы C++

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Задание:

> Написать программу, которая удаляет из двухмерного массива,
>   заполненного случайными числами, строки, содержащие нулевые элементы.

```
void DeleteNullRow(int**& originalArr, int& sizeRow, int& sizeCol) {
    int** originalArrCopy = new int*[sizeRow];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++) {
        originalArrCopy[i] = new int[sizeCol];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeCol; j++) {
            if (originalArr[i][j] != 0) {
                originalArrCopy[i][j] = originalArr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    delete[]originalArr;
    originalArr = originalArrCopy;
    sizeCol--;
```

Значит, вот моя функция удаления строк, содержащих нулевые элементы. Здесь я пытался найти нулевые элементы в массиве, поставил условие и он находит.

В моих мыслях было создать массив копию `int** originalArrCopy = new int*[sizeRow];` которое должен был заполниться уже строки без нулевых элементов.

Я удалил старый массив и записал в нее уже новый. Вроде бы он норм скомпилился, но работает не правильно. Видимо с логикой функции я намудрил что то. Можете подсказать в каких местах именно я ошибся?

Comment: Во-первый, у вас массив указателей, поэтому delete[]originalArr; мало - надо в цикле удалить каждый элемент массива, которые являются указателями на массив (строку исходной матрицы). Во-вторых, в условии вы говорите о строках матрицы, а уменьшаете количество столбцов sizeCol--. В-третьих, внимательно посмотрите на середину метода, цикл в цикле, что в нем делается? Вы просто пропускаете некоторые ячейки новой матрицы, оставляя в них мусор. Ваша реализация не соответствует заданию.

Comment: Да, понял уже, спасибо вам, просто я начинающий программист из-за этого пишу иногда шлак думая что, это правильнно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю смысла ваших телодвижений. Вы создаете новый массив, потом не удаляя полностью старый, перезаписываете, не меняете количество строк в нем...

Просто переписываем прямо по месту ненулевые строки, удаляем лишние, исправляем число строк...

Примерно так:

```
void DeleteNullRow(int** a, int& rows, int cols)
{
    int newRow = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
    {
        bool has0 = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
            if (a[j][i] == 0) { has0 = true; break; }
        if (!has0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
                a[newRow][i] = a[j][i];
            newRow++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = newRow; i < rows; ++i) delete[] a[i];
    rows = newRow;
}
```

Пример полной программы - https://ideone.com/yG1zJi

Comment: забыли delete[] a;

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Не забыл - он не нужен! Ни в коем случае! Вы, похоже, просто не поняли, что делает этот код...

Comment: А, теперь понял. Просто сразу в конец посмотрел

Comment: @Harry Спасибо вам добрый человек, понял уже я свою ошибку и какой бред нес я в коде, просто я начинающий программист из-за этого пишу иногда шлак думая что, это правильнно